# Azure Data Factory(ADF) vs Azure Functions: How to choose?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Currently we are using Blob trigger Azure Functions to move json data into Cosmos DB. We are planning to replace Azure Functions with Azure Data Factory(ADF) pipeline.
I am new to Azure Data Factory(ADF), so not sure, Could Azure Data Factory(ADF) pipeline be better option or not?

Answer (score 12):

Though my answer is a bit late, I would like to add that I would not recommend replacing your current setup with ADF. Reasons:

1. It is too expensive. ADF costs way more than azure functions.
2. Custom Logic: ADF is not built to perform cleansing logics or any custom code. Its primary goal is for data integration from external systems using its vast connector pool
3. Latency: ADF has much higer latency due to the large overhead of its job frameweork

Comment: For simple jobs where you can do it in a minute or so use Azure functions, ADF is really complicated , but if you need to continue fetching for hours (with delays etc ) ADF is ok. Yet still its logging system sucks and cannot control with simple code(yes it has function support).  Actually best cost effective and custom solution is (if you have time) boot your own little vm instance and write custom logic inside it.

Comment: Why should I use a vm, where I need to patch the os by myself, need to implement high availability by myself, have to run the system all day long, even if nothing has to be done, have to prepare a suitable image in advance? All of these steps are not necessary with functions

Comment: I was actually supporting use of Azure Functions for simple jobs, maybe worded incorrectly. For very complex ETL jobs (where not get and copy but do more checks and transform on the way) I was mentioning writing own code.

Answer (score 2):

Based on you requirements, Azure Data Factory is your perfect option. You could follow this [`tutorial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-portal) to configure Cosmos DB Output and Azure Blob Storage Input.

Advantage over azure function is being that you don't need to write any custom code unless there is a data cleaning involved and azure data factory is the recommended option, even if you want azure function for other purposes you can add it within the pipeline.

Comment: Actually, we are also implementing some custom logic in Azure Function before saving into Cosmos DB.(i.e. calling some APIs and bind additional data).. So this custom logic can we implement in Azure Data Factor(ADF) pipeline?

Comment: Thanks! @Sajeetharan for your suggestions.  I didn't downvote.

Comment: I think, this is not a useful answer as it directs to a wrong direction. ADF is not suitable fur these kind of workloads described by the questioner. See my answer below.

Comment: Having used both Data Factory ADF and Functions for a few years now at enterprise terabyte scale, I find Data Factory is extremely good at orchestration of data movement and transformation tasks.  I don't use ADF for transformation outside the Copy activity conversions.  I use Databricks heavily for large scale transformation.  I use Functions for little stuff and external interfacing.  Functions when small t and Databricks when big T.  ADF Cost is TINY.  Function cost "can" explode if you don't control costs carefully.

Answer (score 1):

### Cost

I get images from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56692225/azure-data-factory-copy-from-azure-block-to-cosmosdb-is-slow).

[image]

Let's calculate the cost:

```
if your file is large:
43:51hour=43.867(h)
4(DIU)*43.867(h)*0.25($/DIU-H)=43.867$
43.867/7.514GB= 5.838 ($/GB)

if your file is small(2.497MB), take about 45 seconds:
4(DIU)*1/60(h)*0.25($/DIU-H)=0.0167$
2.497MB/1024MB=0.00244013671 GB
0.0167/0.00244013671= 6.844 ($/GB)
```

### scale

The Max instances Azure function can run is 200.

ADF can run 3,000 Concurrent External activities. And In my test, only 1500 copy activities were running parallel. (This test wasted a lot of money.)

Answer (score 0):

Fundamental use of Azure Data Factory is data ingestion. Azure Functions are Server-less (Function as a Service) and its best usage is for short lived instances. Azure Functions which are executed for multiple seconds are far more expensive. Azure Functions are good for Event Driven micro services. For Data ingestion , Azure Data Factory is a better option as its running cost for huge data will be lesser than azure functions. Also you can integrate Spark processing pipelines in ADF for more advanced data ingestion pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

Moreover , it depends upon your situation . Azure functions are server less light weight processes meant for quick access in response to an event instead of volumetric responses which are meant for batch processes.
So, if your requirement is to quickly respond to an event with little information stay with Azure functions or if you have a need for batch process switch to ADF.